# Get only specific columns from Excel (ACE OLEDB)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb, aceoledb

I am using ACE OLEDB to load an excel file into a DataTable.

I have a list of the columns I need to grab from the file (column names).

Problem is I couldn't find any working source on how to get only those specific columns from the Excel into the DataTable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query columns like you would any other SQL sentence:

`SELECT [columnName1], [columnName2] FROM Sheet1`

columnName should be the value in the header of the column that you are trying to get.

Comment: You may find that 'Sheet1' needs to also be in square brackets.

Comment: How would I skip the first row below the header (empty row) in my SELECT?